# C to MIPS translate

Tags: mips

Here i have been given an exam question that i partly solved but do not understand it completely
why it is used `volatile` here? and the missing expression
 i have must be `switches >>8`.
when it comes to translation i have some difficulty.

Eight switches are memory mapped to the memory address 0xabab0020, where the
least significant bit (index 0) represents switch number 1 and the bit with index 7
represents switch number 8. A bit value 1 indicates that the switch is on and
0 means that it is off. Write down the missing C code expression, such that the
while loop exits if the toggle switch number 8 is off.

```
 volatile int * switches = (volatile int *) 0xabab0020;
 volatile int * leds = (volatile int *) 0xabab0040;
 while(/* MISSING C CODE EXPRESSION */){
   *leds = (*switches >> 4) & 1;
}
```

Translate the complete C code above into MIPS assembly code, including the missing C code expression. You are not allowed to use pseudo instructions.

Comment: We're not here to take orders from you. **What have you tried**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
volatile int * switches = (volatile int *) 0xabab0020;
volatile int * leds = (volatile int *) 0xabab0040;
  while((*switches >> 8) & 1){
    *leds = (*switches >> 4) & 1;
}
```

To mips

```
     lui   $s0,0xabab    #load the upper half
     ori   $s0,0x0020

     lui   $s1,0xabab
     ori   $s1,0x0040
while:
     lw    $t0,0x20($s0)
     srl   $t0,$t0,8     #only the 8th bit is important
     andi  $t0,$t0,1     # clear other bit keep the LSB
     beq   $t0,$0, done
     lw    $t1,0x40($s1)
     srl   $t1,$t1,4
     andi  $t1,$t1,1
     sw    $t1,0x40($s1) 
     j     while
done:
     sw    $t0,0x20($s0)
```

Comment: Your code does not work: You load $s0 with 0xabab0020, then you load $t0 with 0x20($s0) and store at 0x40($s0). "beq $t0,$s0,done" is also incorrect.

Comment: Thanks i changed it now have a look please

Comment: Better. The offsets on the loads and stores are still incorrect. You should have `lw $t0,($s0)`,`lw $t1,($s1)`, `sw $t1,($s1`)` .  The srl is not needed, you can just do: `andi $t0,$t0,0x80` before the `beq`.

Answer (score 2):

without volatile your code can legally be interpreted by the compiler as:

```
int * switches = (volatile int *) 0xabab0020;
int * leds = (volatile int *) 0xabab0040;
*leds = (*switches >> 4) & 1;
while(/* MISSING C CODE EXPRESSION */){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` qualifier is an indication to the `C` compiler that the data at addresses `switches` and `leds` can be changed by another agent in the system. Without the `volatile` qualifier, the compiler would be allowed to optimize references to these variables away.

The problem description says the loop should run while bit 7 of `*switches` is set, i.e: `while (*switches & 0x80 != 0)`

Translating the code is left as an exercise for the reader.